# jShowOff only works in WP when jQuery is in same PHP file?

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, jquery-plugins

I'm using **[jShowOff](http://ekallevig.com/jshowoff/)** in a WordPress theme inside `home.php` within the `<body>`.

Inside the `<head>` in `header.php` I have both jQuery and jShowOff scripts properly included:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js?ver=1.6.1'></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery.jshowoff.min.js"></script>
```

but the jShowOff functionality only works if I also include jQuery inside `home.php` (within the same php file as where I'm putting jShowOff HTML code).

Can anyone think of why this might be or how I can fix it? I shouldn't need to load jQuery twice, right?

Within the `<body>` in `home.php` the code looks like this:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js?ver=1.6.1'></script>

            <div id="basicFeatures">
                <div title="Shore"><a href="http://google.com"><img src="http://farm5.static.flickr.com/4017/4303103738_a4745a3e6d_o.jpg" width=660 height=371 alt="Shore"></a></div>
                <div title="Flower"><a href="http://imgur.com"><img src="http://farm5.static.flickr.com/4067/4302354517_d72d321f17_o.jpg" width=660 height=371 alt="Flower"></a></div>
                <div title="Fern"><a href="http://gmail.com"><img src="http://farm3.static.flickr.com/2739/4303103822_a3b23ff7f5_o.jpg" width=660 height=371 alt="Fern"></a></div>
            </div>
            <script type="text/javascript">     
                $(document).ready(function(){ $('#basicFeatures').jshowoff({ 
                    links: false,
                    controls: false,
                    effect: 'fade',
                    cssClass: 'basicFeatures',
                    hoverPause: false 
                }); });
            </script>
```

Update: Problem solved by switching `$` to `jQuery`:

```
        <script>        
            jQuery(document).ready(function(){ jQuery('#basicFeatures').jshowoff({ 
                links: false,
                controls: false,
                effect: 'fade',
                cssClass: 'basicFeatures',
                hoverPause: false 
            }); });
        </script>
```

Comment: What does your script look like?

Comment: It's the one from [ekallevig.com/jshowoff/](http://ekallevig.com/jshowoff/)

Comment: Hmm, so you are wrapping your javascript in a $(document).ready?  That is the only issue I can think of.

Comment: I think you're right that is the issue but I'm not sure how to rewrite it. I'm reading the ready() documentation now.

Comment: Your code looks correct.  I don't think this an issue with $(document).ready

Comment: Thanks / when I figure it out I will def. post it here.

Comment: All I had to do was change both instances of $ to jQuery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the script include tag in your page's body. Once the page has loaded, open javascript console of your browser and check whether it responds to jQuery and $ both should respond the same object. If they doesn't it means your $ used by some other library. Replace $ with jQuery.

Comment: Thanks / could it be conflicting with PHP somehow? In Firebug in the DOM console it said $ unknown. I tried switching $(document).ready(function() to jQuery().ready(function() but no dice.

Comment: I tried jQuery(document).ready(function() which I think is what you meant. Is it necessary to change the $'s inside [jshowoff.min.js](https://raw.github.com/ekallevig/jShowOff/master/jquery.jshowoff.min.js) too to make that work?

Comment: I didn't see the second $. Once I changed both of them to jQuery it worked. Thank you!

Comment: It won't be the PHP which would have conflicted. It must have been some other javascript library which your wordpress/theme is loading. Its always safe to use jQuery instead of $, but if you still want to use $ you need to wrap everything inside a jQuery object. You can check the code of any plugin like jshowoff.js on how its done. Anyways, great that your problem is solved.